# Safari 16.0 getUserMedia permission prompt is not showing up after disallowing permissions the 3rd time

Tags: safari, getusermedia

Version 16.0 (17614.1.25.9.10, 17614)

I'm currently working on a flow related to allowing user permissions on a certain screen. I tested by clicking `Don't allow` multiple times. For some reason, the popup stops appearing after clicking `Don't allow` 3 times and it stays as denied until I closes the browser. Is this the expected behaviour?